# Can't create a GPU powered VM instance on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gpu, virtual-machine

I'm trying to create a GCP VM Instance with a Tesla P100 GPU. The region I choose is `europe-west1`. I increased some quotas to get a P100 GPU, and I have the following situation:

```
NVIDIA P100 GPUs for europe-west1 set to 1
Committed NVIDIA P100 GPUs for europe-west1 set to 1
GPUs (all regions) set to 1
```

When I try to create the instance I get the following error message:

[image: error image]

```
Quota 'GPUS_ALL_REGIONS' exceeded. Limit: 1.0 globally.
```

I don't know what's wrong with this configuration. I tried I tried contacting GPC support (replying to one of their messages) but they sent me a defult support message with no clues.

Thanks to everybody

Comment: As GPU resources are highly demanded, GPU might not available in that region at the moment. You can try other region or wait for the avalability of the GPU resources.

Comment: Maybe you're right. I tried again after an hour since my last attempt and the instance was created without any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you already requested your [quota increase](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#request_quotas) for your GPU in all regions.

Please take into consideration that Quota increase requests typically take two business days to process.

If you tried before the quote increase has taken effect, you will receive the error message:

`Quota 'GPUS_ALL_REGIONS' exceeded. Limit: 1.0 globally.`

On the other hand, when a GPU is not available in the zone or  region you might receive a different errors:

`ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED`
Or
`ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED_WITH_DETAILS`

If those errors appears you can check the following documentation:

[Troubleshooting VM creation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-vm-creation#resource_availability)